# Escape of Escape character not accepted (Java and MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql

I have a statement for MySQL 5.5.58-0+deb8u1 that looks like this:

```
UPDATE `general` SET `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` = 'null', `MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT_NR` = '5678', `CONTACT1_NAME` =  + 'ss\' where `general`.`uuid` = '06f8417b-c865-11e7-9a86-000c2924bf92'
```

I try to escape the \ (after ss) with

```
string statementEsc = statement.replace('\\', '\\\\');
```

this results in:

```
UPDATE `general` SET `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` = 'null', `MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT_NR` = '5678', `CONTACT1_NAME` =  + 'ss\\' where `general`.`uuid` = '06f8417b-c865-11e7-9a86-000c2924bf92'
```

When trying the query manually, MySQL accepts this query, but the program gives an error

MySQL JDBC Driver Registered
Problem occured at executeUpdate operation : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ss\', `...at line 1
SQL UPDATE operation has been failed: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ss\', ... = '' at line 1.

I don't understand why.

Comment: You'll get it sorted. (in heavy German accent) "Good luck". Sorry. Couldn't resist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a rogue plus sign in there.

```
`CONTACT1_NAME` =  + 'ss\'
```

Hence this SQL is not valid :

```
UPDATE `general` SET `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` = 'null', `MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT_NR` = '5678', `CONTACT1_NAME` =  + 'ss\\' where `general`.`uuid` = '06f8417b-c865-11e7-9a86-000c2924bf92'
```

Suggest you get rid of it in your original String so that you end up with this SQL instead :

```
UPDATE `general` SET `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` = 'null', `MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT_NR` = '5678', `CONTACT1_NAME` =  'ss\\' where `general`.`uuid` = '06f8417b-c865-11e7-9a86-000c2924bf92'
```

Another suggestion is to take a look at [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). I think they will make your life easier.

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you with such an obvious mistake. Nevertheless, using SQL query tool of phpadmin, the query succeeds. That's why I thought the syntax was correct.
I will definitely look in into Prepared Statements, thx.

Answer (score 2):

You had a `+` maybe from copying the code for us.

However this is an excellent opportunity to use a PreparedStatement.

```
String sql = "UPDATE `general` SET `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` = 'null', "
        + "`MAINTENANCE_CONTRACT_NR` = ?, `CONTACT1_NAME` = ? WHERE `general`.`uuid` = ?";
try  (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, 5678);
    stmt.setString(2, "ss\\"); // One backslash
    stmt.setString(3, "06f8417b-c865-11e7-9a86-000c2924bf92");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

By the way `= 'null'` would assign a string "null" to that field.

Answer (score 0):

Though using PreparedStatement is best answer, try going through this class [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). It have methods for Escapes and unescapes Strings for Java, Java Script, HTML, XML, and SQL.